# Phaser Shooting Game

Tags: javascript, phaser

I am making an shooting game in Phaser. I want to control the gun using the arrow keys i.e.: upArrow, DownArrow and Enter

upArrow : is to increase the angle
downArrow : is to decrease the angle
Enter : To hit the target

I do not know, how to do this thing?

Comment: Is this a problem capturing the input or implementing the behaviour?

Comment: Hello I am learning phaser  so I need the sample code for this condition

Comment: This doesn't seem like a specific game dev question. Instead it reads more like a request for others to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about Phaser, but for my pure JS/canvas projects I handle key input with eventListeners. Here is how I do it:

```
var keys = {up:false, left:false, down:false, right:false};
//Add one for every key you want
//Change canvas to the active element
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
   switch(e.keyCode){
      case 38: //38 is keyCode for up arrow
         keys.up=true;
         break;
      case 37: //37 is keyCode for left arrow
         keys.left=true;
         break;
      //And so on... (No default needed)
   }
}
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
   switch(e.keyCode){
      case 38:
         keys.up=false;
         break;
      case 37:
         keys.left=false;
         break;
      //And so on... (No default needed here either)
   }
}
function gameLoop (){
   //Now you can check if the key is pressed or not
   if(keys.up){
      player.moveUp(); //Or whatever you use for moving
   }
   if(keys.left){
      player.moveLeft();
   }
}
```

I have seen similar solutions, but with an array to save the key presses.
To get the keyCodes, I would reccommend using keycode.info.

I hope this helps! (Maybe there is a much simpler way to do it with Phaser)